# rake aborted plugin for redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am trying to install a plugin for redmine version 5.0.1
an error occurs during the installation process, while if installed on redmine version 4.2.6, the plugin is installed correctly. What could be the problem

this plugin https://github.com/credativUK/redmine_email_inline_images

error

```
WARN -- : Creating scope :system. Overwriting existing method Enumeration.system.
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- redmine_email_inline_images/mail_handler_patch
/usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
/usr/src/redmine/plugins/redmine_email_inline_images/init.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/src/redmine/lib/redmine/plugin_loader.rb:31:in `load'
/usr/src/redmine/lib/redmine/plugin_loader.rb:31:in `run_initializer'
/usr/src/redmine/lib/redmine/plugin_loader.rb:108:in `each'
/usr/src/redmine/lib/redmine/plugin_loader.rb:108:in `block in load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in   `instance_exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `block in make_lambda'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:604:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:603:in `catch'   
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:603:in `block in default_terminator'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:199:in `block in halting'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:512:in `block in invoke_before'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:512:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:512:in `invoke_before'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:105:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:88:in `prepare!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:124:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'    
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
/usr/src/redmine/config/environment.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:533:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate_plugins => redmine:plugins:migrate => environment
```

install command `rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: You should mind the plugin compatibility. Unfortunately Redmine 5 brings lots of new changes and old major versions plugins most likely won't work... Unless there are releases made compatible with Redmine 5....

Answer (score 0):

Due to the upgrade to Rails 6.1 and their `zeitwerk` autoloader, plugins not written specifically for Redmine 5.0 (or upgraded with the required compatibility changes) **will not work with Redmine 5**.

The best article I could find for [updating your plugins to Redmine 5 is here](https://zenn.dev/tohosaku/articles/3ccdeb2f38bb07) and unfortunately is is both in Japanese (I used Google translate) as well as does not cover how to upgrade things that a lot of projects need, such as database migration and hook loading.